# Adding losses in Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm trying to find a way to accumulate losses in Keras. This works (for Gaussian-Mixture-Model loss = negative log likelihood) but is not so elegant:

```
def neg_log_likelihood(y, phis, mu, sigmasq):
    a = phis[:, 0]*gaussian_pdf(y, mu[:, 0*t:(0+1)*t], sigmasq[:, 0])
    for i in range(1, k):
        a += phis[:, i]*gaussian_pdf(y, mu[:, i*t:(i+1)*t], sigmasq[:, i])
    loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(a))
    return loss
```

I would rather create a new variable for the losses, and accumulate everything there. E.g., I tried:

```
def neg_log_likelihood(y, phis, mu, sigmasq):
    losses = tf.Variable(np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float32))
    for i in range(k):
        losses.assign_add(phis[:, i]*gaussian_pdf(y, mu[:, i*t:(i+1)*t], sigmasq[:, i]))
    loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(losses))
    return loss
```

but this fails to produce gradients for some reason. I.e., when I call:

```
gradients_init = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
```

I get `None`.

Anyway to overcome this?

EDIT: here's `gaussian_pdf`, though this is not the problem, as the first example also uses it.

```
def gaussian_pdf(x, mu, sigmasq):
    return (1/tf.math.sqrt(2*math.pi*sigmasq)) * tf.exp((-1/(2*sigmasq)) * tf.norm((x-mu),ord=2,axis=1)**2)
```

Comment: can you give more details on the signature of `gaussian_pdf`?

Comment: @Marat I added, though I don't think this is the problem... The main issue is that the variable I created doesn't seem to keep the gradients...

Comment: The idea is that you don't really need a loop there and this function should be vectorized. I am struggling to understand the variable meanings  and I hoped `gaussian_pdf` would give enough context. `a` seems to be a 0/1 sample x dim class matrix; `y` seems to be sample x dim point coordinates. I still can't understand what is `t`, why means look to be a matrix, and why variances are 1-dimensional